# What do we call for the number satisfying i^n=0?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, complex-numbers

We call i a dual number if it satisfies $$i^2=0$$

In matrix representation, it's
$$
        i^2=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}^2=0
$$

Now I have a number satisfying $$ j^3=0 $$ where $$ j \ne j^2 \ne j^3 $$ In matrix representation, it's

$$
        j^3=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}^3=0
$$

But what do we call for this number j? If I recall correctly, it's not a higher dimensional dual number as its basis is only univariate. Also, I have seen its application in automatic differentiation.

Thanks!

Comment: If an element $a^n=0$ for some natural $n$, then $a$ is said to be nilpotent. I'm not sure of a specific case when $n=3$.

Comment: Just something come up in my mind: How about the name for the case i^n=1 and i^n=-1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A square matrix $A$ is clled nilpotent if $A^n=0$ for some positive integer $n$

Comment: Yes nilpotent is indeed the correct name. Sorry for being greedy, do you know the name for the case i^n=1 and i^n=-1 too?